# Binary array in python time series

Tags: python, arrays, series

how do i turn below into a data frame where array 1 is a column of values and array 2 is a corresponding column of values? This is actually a time series.

```
 [array([[-1.30200473e-06, -9.16726747e-06, -3.99315231e-06, ...,
     -2.22118817e-06, -1.18586385e-05, -6.06567886e-20]])
  array([0.000000e+00, 1.000000e-02, 2.000000e-02, ..., 2.993340e+04,
    2.993341e+04, 2.993342e+04])                                ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
my_array = np.array([np.array([1, 2]), np.array([3, 4])])

pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(my_array))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
   0  1
0  1  3
1  2  4
```